# Windows XP not showing a Hardware ID for Monitors

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I am having a small problem. I have a monitor that I attach to a device, and when I go into device manager, its showing Default Monitor with a Hardware ID of "Monitor\Default_Monitor".

If I attach another monitor (same brand and model, just an older revision) it changes to Plug and Play Monitor, with the Hardware ID of "Monitor\NCR5966".

I have tried uninstalling drivers, and updating drivers, but I can not get the new revision monitor to show up with a Hardware ID.

Any thoughts?

Comment: A new device might not work correctly with an ancient operating system.

Comment: Thats what I am assuming. Trying to find some way around it, and it is not looking good.

Comment: Updating Windows isn't an option?